# Training on multi-GPUs with a small batch size

Tags: tensorflow

I am running TensorFlow on a machine which has two GPUs, each with 3 GB memory. My batch size is only 2GB, and so can fit on one GPU. Is there any point in training with both GPUs (using `CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES`)? If I did, how would TensorFlow distribute the training?

Answer (score 0):

With regards to memory: I assume that you mean that one data batch is 2GB. However, Tensorflow also requires memory to store variables as well as hidden layer results etc. (to compute gradients). For this reason it also depends on your specific model whether or not the memory will be enough. Your best bet would be to just try with one GPU and see if the program crashes due to memory errors.

With regards to distribution: Tensorflow doesn't do this automatically at all. Each op is placed on some device. By default, if you have any number of GPUs available, all GPU-compatible ops will be placed on the first GPU and the rest on the CPU. This is despite Tensorflow reserving all memory on all GPUs by default.

You should have a look at [the GPU guide on the Tensorflow website](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/using_gpu). The most important thing is that you can use the `with tf.device` context manager to place ops on other GPUs. Using this, the idea would be to split your batch into X chunks (X = number of GPUs) and define your model on each device, each time taking the respective chunk as input and making sure to reuse variables.

If you are using `tf.Estimator`, there is some information [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47223766/how-to-run-tensorflow-estimator-on-multiple-gpus-with-data-parallelism). It is very easy to do distributed execution here using just two simple wrappers, but I personally haven't been able to use it successfully (pretty slow and crashes randomly with a segfault).